# Is it חִסָרון or חֶסרון?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

In this [Lechem Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Lehem_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.1.5.1?vhe=ToratEmet&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) on the Rambam in Hilchos Deos says "ונראה לפרש דקצה ראשון הוא החסרון וקצה אחרון התוספת". Is it correct to put the nekudos as חִסָרון or חֶסרון?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's any way to know what the *Lechem Mishne* intended. In Ecclesiastes (*Koheles*) 1:15 it's חֶסְרוֹן *chesron* (the only time either word appears in *Tanach*). In modern Hebrew it's חִסָּרוֹן *chisaron* (and חֶסְרוֹן *chesron* is the [construct](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_state)).